# Category slug field missing with registered custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have registered a new taxonomy term using the same code on two different sites. On one site (a vanilla install), If I go to my taxonomy term in the admin menu, I see a 'slug' option for the add category screen. On my other site, with all plugins disabled, this slug option does not appear.

Anyone know what might cause this?

Register taxonomy code:

```
register_taxonomy( 'my_topics', 
array( 'post', 'page' ), 
array( 'hierarchical' => true, 
'label' => 'my Categories', 
'query_var' => 'topics', 
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'topics')
) );
```

Comment: *@codecowboy* - I hate to ask this but both sites are WordPress v3.x? And where is the drop down you refer to? Your description makes me think you mean this: http://bit.ly/9tkhDG but it's not a drop down. What's the URL path in the admin where you are having trouble?

Comment: Yep I did mean that. Sorry - the question title is misleading. I'll change it.

Comment: From looking at the code, I think this might be related to whether global terms is enabled or not but I can't find the option to switch that on or off either. And yes, both sites are 3.x and are upgrades from WPMU 2.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for global_terms_enabled for multisite is stored in wp_sitemeta

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-edit-category-slug-wpmu-how-to-make-it-work-with-last-wpmu-30

I switched this to off and the category slug field reappears. If anyone can comment on whether its safe to switch this off, that would be greatly appreciated.